# NativeScript Vue Android Live Wallpaper

Tags: android, vue.js, nativescript

I have the app running the way I want, but want to be able to set the app as a live wallpaper.

Editing AndroidManifest.xml, I am able to see the app in the wallpaper chooser, but selecting it causes the app to crash (probably due to lack of a "preview".

```
    <!-- Live Wallpaper service -->
    <service
        android:name="MyWallpaperService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:label="HDLW"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" ></action>
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
            android:resource="@xml/livewallpaper" >
        </meta-data>
    </service>
```

The livewallpaper.xml contains the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wallpaper
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:thumbnail="@drawable/icon"
    android:settingsActivity="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"
     />
```

`com.tns.NativeScriptActivity` seems to be what runs main.js, and setting `android:settingsActivity` to it allows the settings icon to actually load the app and show it.

So my questions are:

1) How to I make `com.tns.NativeScriptActivity` also run in the wallpaper preview? and
2) How do I actually set the `com.tns.NativeScriptActivity` as the wallpaper?

Comment: Is there a crash log? What's in the console? What about the adb logcat?

Comment: how about adding some `NativeScriptActivity`, which probably should be called `SettingsActivity` instead? while setting an `Activity` as a `wallpaper` sounds absurd to me.

Comment: vue.js also sounds more alike a WebView, the terms "native" and "script" contradict each other much ... see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl